# JQUERY - sticky div next to img

Tags: jquery, html, fixed, sticky, floating

I'm spending hours now on this task by now, just CAN'T figure it out. 
I'm building like "9gag" template.. and I'm stuck on the part "floating" div next to the images.
I found good solution in the library : http://viget.com/inspire/jquery-stick-em 
but no mattter what I have tried I just can't implement it, I followed the instruction but still no results. 
here's the fiddle for the concept :     http://jsfiddle.net/g90uocw1/2/

In the stickem library they said i need to use this classes :

```
.stickem-container {
    position: relative;
}

.stickit {
    margin-left: 660px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.stickit-end {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

but even when im trying to add them it's screws the page up :\

I just cant implement it. i have noticed it's wide problem.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @user13286 for some reason when i add the classes it wont work.

Comment: @user13286 i even tried to build it up from the demo to the my concept and again it dosent work, is there any way i even pay you using paypal and you will help me implement it?

Comment: @roim Instead of explaining what is not working, Can you explain what exactly are you trying to achieve..? What should happen in that fiddle..?

Comment: @TJ sorry im a little but stressed out of it..in the end(using the library or not),i want that the left div will "stick" to the right div.this is what im exactly trying to achieve : http://www.10gag.co.il/ the left div sticks to the right div. btw * - this web uses the library i posted above.. but i just cant implement it